# Objects in Arrays: Unexpected String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the above error in this code:

```
var inputs = {
    $("<input>").attr({"type":"hidden","name":"collegeID"}).val(collegeID),
    $("<input>").attr({"type":"hidden","name":"collegeID"}).val(collegeID),
    $("<input>").attr({"type":"hidden","name":"collegeID"}).val(collegeID),
    $("<input>").attr({"type":"hidden","name":"collegeID"}).val(collegeID),
    $("<input>").attr({"type":"hidden","name":"collegeID"}).val(collegeID),
    $("<input>").attr({"type":"hidden","name":"collegeID"}).val(collegeID) 
}
```

This looks pretty valid to me.  I want to `.append()` the variable on to a div and I dont want to have to create a bunch of different variables to do that.

Comment: Object syntax is `{ key: value }`

Comment: You use square brackets (`[]`) for array literals. Curly brackets are for objects meaning it expects key-value pairs.

Comment: objects needs to have keys and values

Comment: Your creating an object literal from a list of objects.  I guess you want `inputs = []` to create an array?

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Thanks! That worked straight away lol, I didn't know that in Javascript.

Answer (score 6):

`inputs` need to be an `Array`. use `[]` instead of `{}`

```js
var collegeID = "";
var inputs = [
  $("<input>").attr({
    "type": "hidden",
    "name": "collegeID"
  }).val(collegeID),
  $("<input>").attr({
    "type": "hidden",
    "name": "collegeID"
  }).val(collegeID),
  $("<input>").attr({
    "type": "hidden",
    "name": "collegeID"
  }).val(collegeID),
  $("<input>").attr({
    "type": "hidden",
    "name": "collegeID"
  }).val(collegeID),
  $("<input>").attr({
    "type": "hidden",
    "name": "collegeID"
  }).val(collegeID),
  $("<input>").attr({
    "type": "hidden",
    "name": "collegeID"
  }).val(collegeID)
]

console.log(JSON.stringify(inputs));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```